# mysql sort by number with dots

Tags: mysql

i have a column with name title with rows :

- 1.8.8
- 1.8.9
- 1.9.1
- 1.9.2
- 1.8.10

and I need sort like this

- 1.8.8
- 1.8.9
- 1.8.10
- 1.9.1
- 1.9.2

is any way how to make it? (type of column is varchar)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471237/sorting-ordering-problem-in-mysql/5471419#5471419

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clunky, but should work provided all of your entries are in the format x.x.x:

```
select yourColumn
from yourTable
order by
cast(substring_index(yourColumn,'.',1) as unsigned),
cast(substring_index(substring_index(yourColumn,'.',2),'.',-1) as unsigned),
cast(substring_index(substring_index(yourColumn,'.',3),'.',-1) as unsigned)
;
```

Comment: glad it helped! Could you accept the answer to indicate that it answered your question, please?

Answer (score 3):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table(legal VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('1.8.8'),('1.8.9'),('1.9.1'),('1.9.2'),('1.8.10');

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY INET_ATON(legal);

+--------+
| legal  |
+--------+
| 1.8.8  |
| 1.8.9  |
| 1.8.10 |
| 1.9.1  |
| 1.9.2  |
+--------+
```

Note that this is a hack. In consequence, it has certain limitations. That said, there's a high likelihood that it will work fine for your purposes.

Comment: holly crap that worked like a charm, i was trying to solve this for ages

Comment: Yes this only works for the format of 255.255.255.255, it will not work for numbers beyond 255. Should be carefully used. I suggest to use Abdul Rehman's solution in this post which is ORDER BY `COLUMN_NAME` *1 worked for very well in my case.

Comment: @WajiraWeerasinghe No. That's an answer to a subtly different problem.

Answer (score 2):

It may help, Simple and Exact Answer:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `TABLENAME` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `COLUMN_NAME` *1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called "natural sort" and there is no way to perform natural sort in MySQL: [Natural Sort in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)

You can solve it by using special sorting field. With values like:

10808
10809
10901
10902
10910
(leading zeros)

PS as a bonus - sorting integers works muuuuch faster than sorting strings (especially strings with some magic rules). Especially if you create sorting index.

Answer (score 0):

none of the answer quite were practical(either wrong or not performant).
Let's think your varchar column with dots is productId then you must use:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_TABLE ORDER BY productId * 1,length(productId)
```

`productId * 1` gives you the same result as `INET_ATON(productId)` and they both are incomplete.

```
0.0.0
0.0
0
```

I got a result like that so to fix that just added `length(productId)`.

```
0
0.0
0.0.0
```

and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Slight different problem. I have a lists that looks like as follows:

- 1
- 1.1
- 1.2
- ...
- 1.10
- 1.10.1
- 1.11

I resolved my problem in MariaDB using REGEXP_REPLACE inserting leading "0":

ORDER BY REGEXP_REPLACE(kKey,'.([[:<:]][1-9])[[:>:]]', '.0\1');

I have a maximum of 2 digits after "." So I replace all dots followed by a single number ([[:<:]][1-9])[[:>:]] between word boundaries and capture the number. It is then replaced with '.0' + captured number.