# How to sort floating price values stored as varchar in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

OK ,
I have a little problem with some values from database
,i have 2 diferent type of value because i have column Price (varchar) and the problem is like that

[[image: picture]]

i try to cast `select price from products order by CAST(price AS SIGNED)  asc` but without result because price without "." is not sorted very well

Thanks !

Comment: Why store price as `VARCHAR` ? Store it as `DECIMAL` if there are cents, `INTEGER` if the currency does not have cents.

Comment: if i change type (external api will crush the database ,the script who insert automatic dates in my database don't know about that type ,trust me i have 160 columns on that table all are varchar ) i know what you say but i can't change type (i must find a solution on that )

Comment: `ORDER BY REPLACE(price,'.','')` ??

Comment: take a look on this result @KikiTheOne http://imgur.com/a/IlmdU

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471237/sorting-ordering-in-mysql/5471419#5471419

Comment: This is works for me SELECT *  FROM `product` ORDER BY CAST(replace(price,".","") AS DECIMAL(18,4)) DESC thanks  all for help

Answer (score 4):

You should choose `DECIMAL` datatype for storing your price values.

In order to bypass the problem for the time being you can use any of the following methods:

**Method 1:** `...ORDER BY price+0 ASC..`

**OR**

**Method 2:** `...ORDER BY CAST(price AS DECIMAL(18,4))...`

---

**Note:**

Better change the datatype of your `price` column to `DECIMAL(18,4)`

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY price DECIMAL(18,4);
```

If you introduce this change then you `ORDER BY price ASC` would suffice.

Comment: There are the same rezults

Comment: Note that casting in query will slow down query speeds.

Comment: @Raptor is there any good way to solve this issue? I am also facing the same. But now its working fine as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Using correct data type to store data is the first thing to do. Please, work hard to do it.